# Express-Passport Local Authentication not working for safari browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, safari, passport.js, express-session

please note that I am a beginner in node js so apologies in advance.

```
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + uiDir));
        app.use(cookieParser('SecretKey')); 
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
        app.use(session({
           secret: 'SecretKey',
            resave: true,
            saveUninitialized: true,
            rolling:'true',
            cookie:{
                maxAge: 60*1000*30, 
                secure:true,
                httpOnly: true,
            }
        }));

        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session()); 
        app.use(helmet({
            frameguard: {
                action: 'sameorigin'
            }
        }));
        app.use(flash()); 



       passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
            done(null, user.username);
       }); 

        passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
            done(null, user);
        });     
       passport.use('local',new LocalStrategy(

                function(username, password, done) {

                var loginqry = {
                    jsonrpc: '2.0',
                                id: 12,
                        method: 'call',
                        params: [ 'toIntergrateLater', 'users', 
                                 'authenticate',

                                  {"username":username,
                                  "password":password
                                  } 

                        ]
                };

                BackendAuthservice.auth(loginqry,function(data){                

                   if(data.result.error=="Wrong password"){                                        
                     return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password.' });
                    }
                    if(data.result.error=="User not found"){
                         return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found' });
                    }   

                    else{
                        data.result.status = true;
                        return done(null,data );
                    }
                });
      }));
```

This code is working fine for IE, Firefox, Chrome, Mac-google-chrome but **when I access MAC Safari (req.user) is coming undefined**. please help

incoming request from safari for which I am getting req.user undefined on success-redirect of passport-js

Comment: hi abhijeet, did you find a solution for this? I am encountering the exact same issue.

Comment: Hi @bprdev,

The browser was sending a request with the current time to my express server,
but my server PC on getting factory reset was showing time of 15days past from   current date and express session timeout was of only 30mins.

Because of which browser was sending a response with expired cookie,
as a result 'Set-cookie' was not getting called. 

Syncing my express server system with NTP fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing **user** instead of **user.username** in the done callback.
The deserialize method must take username as an argument if user.username is passed in the serialize user.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
   });
```